# Adding value to existing value in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a

```
{
"name": "Banana",
"quantity": 5
}
```

in "Products" db. What I need is to add (e.g) 200 to "quantity" so "quantity" will be 205 at the end. I'm new to MongoDB&mongoose.
I tried

```
const result = await Product.updateOne({ 
       'name' : req.params.name 
    },
    {
        $set: {
            quantity: this.quantity+req.body.quantity
        }
    }
)
```

but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `$inc` operator:

```js
const result = await Product.updateOne({ 
    'name' : req.params.name 
},
{
    $inc: {
        quantity: req.body.quantity
    }
})
```